# Show only column number in VSCode status bar

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code

**Problem:**
VSCode has a status bar at the bottom. In every text file there is this item/widget that represents on what line and column you currently are — `Ln 7, Col 5` (line 7, character 5).

How do I make it so that this thing shows only the `Col` value? I can already see line number in my editor and having it in the status bar as well is only a visual clutter for me.

**What I tried:**
There might be and extension that shows only a column number. This way you could hide the default `Ln x, Col x` and use an extension instead. But I couldn't find anything that would function this way.

Comment: if you get such an extension, not hard to write, you also lose the multi cursor info, char selection count and maybe more